# Swift 3 : binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type int and 'Int?'

Tags: arrays, swift, swifty-json

I am getting the error when trying to make a for loop like this

```
for i in  0..<firstJSON["boxGroups"].array?.count{
   existingGroups.append(firstJSON["boxGroups"][0]["name"].stringValue)
 }
```

Xcode is complaining  "binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type int and 'Int?'"

Answer (score 4):

The issue you are facing is because of [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), `array` property return optional type so that your count property is also return optional object. So batter to wrapped the optional with `if let` or `guard let`.

Also in `for loop` instead of using `i` to access every object of array you are only accessing first object using `0`.

```
if let boxGroupsArray = firstJSON["boxGroups"].array {
    for i in  0..<boxGroupsArray.count{
         existingGroups.append(boxGroupsArray[i]["name"].stringValue)
    }
}
```

There is better option using `flatMap` instead of `for loop`

```
if let boxGroupsArray = firstJSON["boxGroups"].array {
    existingGroups = boxGroupsArray.flatMap { $0["name"].string }
}
```

Comment: If the `existingGroups` array is optional, it is also possible to do this: `existingGroups = firstJSON["boxGroups"].array.flatMap({ $0["name"].stringValue })`.

Comment: my point was that if OP wants the array to be optional he could do it that way. No use in allocating memory for an empty array if it's not going to be used, should be optional with nil as initial value. And yes, you can call `flatMap` on optional arrays without unwrapping using the `?`.

Comment: @Laffen Yes I have just check its working, but its better if you ignore the use of optional because it will increase the `optional chaining` in your code also for prevent crashing need to wrapped optional using `guard let` or `if let`

Comment: I believe we could have a long and interesting discussion about this subject, but I guess you've answered OPs question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
for i in  0..<firstJSON["boxGroups"].array!.count{
   existingGroups.append(firstJSON["boxGroups"][0]["name"].stringValue)
 }
```

Comment: Only if you want the program to crash the first time it comes across a nil array.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply - I guess this is the better way :-)

```
for innerJSON in firstJSON["boxGroups"].array!{                          
  existingGroups.append(innerJSON["boxGroups"].stringValue)
}
```

Comment: The batter option here is to use `flatMap` instead of `for loop`, check my edited answer. Also your answer doesn't specify the why you are getting this error.

Comment: That's a bad way. Your program will crash if `firstJSON["boxGroups"].array` is nil.

Comment: I'm completely agree with JermyP better if you unwrapped the optional array like I have done, instead of forcefully wrapping it.